# Shortest way in Ruby to convert "John Di Bello" in "John DI BELLO"

Tags: ruby, string

I'm trying to find the most efficient way in Ruby to transform a *String* `"John Di Bello"` in `"John DI BELLO"`.

Basically I need `capitalize` on the name that is always the first word and `upcase`on the surname that can also be composed of two words.

At this moment I'm upcasing everything

```
authors = ['John Di Bello', 'Terry Payton']
authors.map { |a| a.upcase }
#=> ['JOHN DI BELLO', 'TERRY PAYTON']
```

I cannot find an easy way to capitalize the first word in every array item.

Answer (score 3):

Split it, capitalize *and* upcase, then join it.

```
['John Di Tri Bello', 'Terry Payton'].map do |s|
  s.
    split(/\s+/, 2).
    reduce { |n, s| [n.capitalize, s.upcase] }.
    join(' ')
end
#⇒ ["John DI TRI BELLO", "Terry PAYTON"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Other option, map with:

```
string.partition(' ').first + string.partition(' ')[1..-1].join.upcase
```

So, it becomes:

```
array.map { |s| s.partition(' ').first + s.partition(' ')[1..-1].join.upcase }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like expand upon [mudasobwas answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52559852/3982562), since the use of *reduce* in this scenario might be a bit cryptic. A more expresive way of writing the solution might be:

```
authors = ['John Di Bello', 'Terry Payton']

authors.map do |name|
  first_name, last_name = name.split(' ', 2)
  "#{first_name.capitalize} #{last_name.upcase}"
end
#=> ["John DI TRI BELLO", "Terry PAYTON"]
```

You could wrap `first_name, last_name = ...` in parentheses to make more clear that you are using array decomposition eg. `(first_name, last_name) = ...` but it is not necessary.

**References:**

- [`Array#map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-map)
- [`String#split`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-split)
- [`String#capitalize`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-capitalize)
- [`String#upcase`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-upcase)
- [Array Decomposition](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition)

Answer (score 0):

Where possible, I prefer modifying strings in place, rather than converting them to arrays, modifying the array then joining the results back into a string (a [foible](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/foible), perhaps). Also, in 2018 shouldn't we be supporting Unicode?<sup>1</sup>

```
def capitalize_then_upcase(str)
  str.gsub(/\p{Alpha}+/).with_index { |s,i| i.zero? ? s.capitalize : s.upcase }
end

arr = ['JohN di Bello', 'Hopalong Cassidy', 'Franz Josef Strauß']

arr.map { |str| capitalize_then_upcase(str) }
  #=> ["John DI BELLO", "Hopalong CASSIDY", "Franz JOSEF STRAUSS"]
```

This uses the form of [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-gsub) where an enumerator is returned when there is no block.

`\p{Alpha}` could be replaced with `[[:alpha:]]`. Both match Unicode letters (uppercase and lowercase). For documentation, search for those as strings in [Regexp](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Regexp.html).

<sup>1. See [this article](https://blog.honeybadger.io/ruby-s-unicode-support/) concerning [String#upcase](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-upcase)'s (and presumably [String#capitalize](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-capitalize)'s) support of Unicode.</sup>

Comment: [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_orthography) says, "The capital ẞ [of ß] was declared an official letter of the German alphabet on 29 June 2017." Does Ruby have some catching up to do? Perhaps a German wordsmith could enlighten us.